# Template argument deduction Doesn't Work for Function Template <unresolved overloaded function type>

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++17, template-argument-deduction

I am trying to understand how template argument deduction works in C++. And so writing out different examples. One such example which doesn't work and i can't understand why is given below:

```
#include<iostream>
template<int var, typename T>
void func (T x)
{
    std::cout<<x<<std::endl;
}

template<typename T>
void SomeFunc(T a)
{
    a(6);
}
int main()
{
    
    
    func<5, int>(10);//this work as expected
    func<5>(20);//this works as well using template argument deduction
    
   
    SomeFunc(func<5,int>) ;//this works as well
    
    
    //the next two calls doesn't work
    
    SomeFunc(func<5>);//this doesn't work. Why doesn't template argument deduction works here
    SomeFunc(func<5>(20));//this doesn't work either.
   
    
    return 0;
}
```

In the above example, the statement `SomeFunc(func<5>);` doesn't work. My thinking is that when the compiler tries to instantiates `SomeFunc<>` it needs its template type parameter. But we have passed `func<5>` as the function call argument  without actually calling(specifying the call argument to func itself) `func` so there is no way to deduce the second parameter and so it doesn't work. My **first question** is that is my analysis of why this call fails correct? If not then why doesn't it work.

Next in the statement `SomeFunc(func<5>(20));` i have specified the function call argument `20` to `func` which was not specified in the previous call. But still this statement doesn't work. **Why is this so**?

While reading about template argument deduction i also came across the following statement:

> Deduction only works for immediate calls.

But i could not understand what the above quoted statement means. It may have to do something with the fact that complete type or incomplete type used as template argument but i am not sure.

Comment: `func` returns `void`.  You can't have an object of type void which is what `SomeFunc` is trying to do.

Comment: But then how does `SomeFunc(func<5,int>) ;` work? Here we have the same function template `func` that returns `void`

Comment: `func<5,int>` doesn't call the function.  Instead it names a function object, which decays into a function pointer with the address to the `func<5,int>` function.

Comment: `func<5>` doesn’t work because the compiler has no clue what the second template argument is when passing the function pointer. When you call the function, it returns void, so it breaks. `func<5, int>` works because it is passing `func<5,int>` function pointer into `SomeFunc`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- ```
  SomeFunc(func<5,int>);
  ```

  You pass a pointer to the function `func<5,int>` and `T` becomes `void(*)(int)` which is fine. It also works *inside* `SomeFunc` when you use the function pointer `a` to call the function it is pointing at.
- ```
  SomeFunc(func<5>);
  ```

  Deduction is not possible. The compiler is not able to look forward to see that inside `SomeFunc` you will call `a(6)` so therefore it must instantiate `func<5,int>` and make `a` point at it.
- ```
  SomeFunc(func<5>(20));
  ```

  Here you actually call `func<5,int>` (with the argument `20`) and pass the return value from that call into `SomeFunc`. There is no return value from `func<5,int>` since it's `void` and `void a;` is not valid. If it *had* been valid, the next problem would have been that you try to call `a` in `SomeFunc`. The argument to `SomeFunc` must be a callable of some sort or else `a(6);` will fail.

Comment: Yes, `func<5,int>` instantiates the actual function, so what's passed to `SomeFunc` isn't a pointer to a function template but to a real function. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/e8PT79oWW)

Comment: @JasonLiam ... and [here are](https://godbolt.org/z/KdvhMsKGo) a few more options.

Answer (score 2):

`func<5>` is an invalid call to `func` since you must use parentheses to call a function even for functions that take 0 parameters. As for the second error, `func<5>(20)` is valid since the compiler is able to deduce T from the function's parameter type. However, you cannot have void variables. Thus, calling `SomeFunc` with a void value is invalid, since `a` cannot be a void parameter.

```cpp
static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(func<5>(20)), void>);

SomeFunc(func<5>(20)); // T is deduced as void
```